# SerialPort DataReceived Event Threading

Tags: c#, serial-port

According to MSDN for the `DataReceived` event, it says

> The DataReceived event is raised on a secondary thread when data is received from the SerialPort object.

Does this mean there is just one secondary thread that always fires the event?  Or does the SerialPort object create a new thread each time it fires the `DataReceived` event?  So could my `DataReceived` event fire while I'm in the `DataReceived` event?

I tried to google this but couldn't find a good answer.

Comment: Same event every time.  You register the event once using '+='.  If you close the connection then each time it is opened you would need to register and then would be different every time.

Comment: I get that it's the same event every time, but the event is being called from a thread from the SerialPort object.  If that thread is different every time then it would be possible to call that event from another thread while you were in that event doing something else.  However, if it were being called from the same thread then it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: An invent is an interrupt which automatically switches processes and can be be called from anywhere in the app.

Comment: You can check it by actually operating it. Thread ID should be acquired by this API. [Thread.ManagedThreadId Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this post on the MSDN forums [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e36193cd-a708-42b3-86b7-adff82b19e5e/how-does-serialport-handle-datareceived?forum=netfxbcl).

> When it does, data received in your case, it dips in the ThreadPool
>   and calls QueueUserWorkItem() which allocates a thread pool thread to
>   call your DataReceived event handler.  It then immediately calls
>   WaitCommEvent() again to wait for the next "something interesting".

It sounds like the `SerialPort` object uses a `ThreadPool` so although the `DataReceived` event is being called on different `Threads`, they already exist in the `ThreadPool` and therefor there is no overhead for creating new ones.

So it is possible to have the event fire even while you are in there because it will be on a different Thread.